# Android ExpandableListView setGroupIndicator?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Is there a way to set different group indicators for different groups in ExpandableListView.
I have tried **setGroupIndicator** but it then sets all the groups indicator with same icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about a nicer way to do that. I simply removed the groupIndicator and added one manually which I change accordingly in getGroupView of my ExpandableListAdpater...